# How does bytes.__repr__ representation work?

Tags: python, byte

`bytes` are immutable sequences of integers in the range of 0 <= x < 256.

How does `bytes.__repr__` work?

Why is `\x` escaping sometimes used, and other times not used? e.g `bytes([118, 255])` is displayed as `b'v\xff'` with only one `\x`. I understand that `\x` is used to communicate values that falls outside the ascii range? Is there anything else going on here?

I'm looking for a in-depth explanation of how this works? Maybe even point me to the CPython source code for these features.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The code of interest seems to be [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1386):

```
if (c == quote || c == '\\')
    *p++ = '\\', *p++ = c;
else if (c == '\t')
    *p++ = '\\', *p++ = 't';
else if (c == '\n')
    *p++ = '\\', *p++ = 'n';
else if (c == '\r')
    *p++ = '\\', *p++ = 'r';
else if (c < ' ' || c >= 0x7f) {
    *p++ = '\\';
    *p++ = 'x';
    *p++ = Py_hexdigits[(c & 0xf0) >> 4];
    *p++ = Py_hexdigits[c & 0xf];
}
else
    *p++ = c;
```

If `c < ' ' || c >= 0x7f`, the escape sequence with `\x` is used. (`0x7f` is 127, BTW). Everything before `' '` on the ASCII table is a special character. See http://www.asciitable.com/. Everything on the first column would be escaped by `repr`. Note that backslashes, quotes, line breaks, carriage returns, and tabs are considered special cases.